# Handling the android App when user swipes the app from resent Apps list

Tags: android, android-activity, state, swipe, detect

In my app there are 4 activity :
Activity Launcher, Activity A, Activity B & Activity C.

Activity Launcher is launcher activity and Activity A is the first Activity that App starts from it.

When App be closed in background (not be killed by swiping the user from resent list) in Activity Launcher I receive the name of last Activity (A, B or C) (from database) in order to intent by startActivityForResult method to A, B or C for recovery each of A, B or C activities.

My problem is when App be killed by swiping the user from resent list and click the App icon again, the App runs from last activity because of I can't detect whenever App be killed by swiping the user.

I want find out that whenever App be killed in order to reset database and subsequently App runs from first Activity (A).

Comment: Swiping app away from recents force kills the process and you won't receive any callbacks for it. This is made so user can stop apps that are stuck or misbehave.

Comment: There is no way to know if your app was killed. But why do you care? Android kills off apps that are in the background and haven't been used for awhile, that's the way it works. What difference does it make? I think you are trying to do something that isn't necessary.